# dbm.error: db type could not be determined

Tags: python

I installed Python 3.7.3, and I cannot correctly run the module no matter which version I'm using. Here is my latest error message. This problem has been occuring with me for weeks, and not even my teacher understands this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wimme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shelve.py", line 243, in open
    return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
  File "C:\Users\wimme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shelve.py", line 227, in __init__
    Shelf.__init__(self, dbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
  File "C:\Users\wimme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\dbm\__init__.py", line 88, in open
    raise error[0]("db type could not be determined")
dbm.error: db type could not be determined
```

Here is the source code for my file.

```
import shelve
import pickle

scores_file = shelve.open('scores.txt', 'c')


name = input('Input student name (-999 to quit):')

while name != '-999':


    if (name in scores_file):
        print('This name has already been entered')

    else:
        score = eval(input('Input student score:'))
        scores_file[name]=score
        print()
    name = input('Input student name (-999 to quit):')


print(scores_file)
scores_file.sync()

want_name = input("Do you want to search for a student score? (yes or no)")

while want_name == 'yes':
    #print(scores_file.keys())
    print(list(scores_file.keys()))
    search_name = input("Which student's score would you like to know?")
    print(search_name in scores_file)
    if search_name in scores_file:
         print(search_name , "scored a" , scores_file[search_name])
    else:
         print("This student's score is not in this list")

    want_name = input("Do you want to search for another student score? (yes or no)")

scores_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a python library issue, not an IDE issue.

The traceback is missing the line of your code where the error occurred.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  If the answer below is not correct, and in the future, delete the extraneous cruff.  I suspect only `import shelve` and `shelve.open` are needed.

Both run fine on my Win 10 machine, with same arguments, creating a DbfilenameShelf object.  For me, scores.txt did not exist previously.  I believe it must have for you.

Reading dbm.py, starting at line 88, dbm.whichdb(file) must have returned ''.  That in turn means that all the checks in the whichdb code, to return something else, failed.  In particular, scores.txt must already exist, so that the following, lines 151-154, did not return None.

```
    try:
        f = io.open(filename, "rb")
    except OSError:
        return None
```

At this point, the file did not look like a GNU dbm, and a dumbdbm was already checked for, so '' was returned.

So use a non-existent name unless you already have a database.  Leave .txt off as dumbdbm will create filename.dat and filename.dir.  The shelve.open doc says "The filename specified is the base filename for the underlying database. As a side-effect, an extension may be added to the filename and more than one file may be created."